# MVC 3 form action parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC and just started using 3.0.  When I load a a partial view, that contains a form, using jquery I've noticed that a parameter gets added to the action:

```
/hi/address/edit/1?_=1297158351246&amp;{}
```

The ascx file contains the following:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<% } %>
```

I realise I can call the following code to remove the parameter, but I would like to know why the extra parameter and what's it's purpose?

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("edit", "address")) { %>
<% } %>
```

**UPDATE:**

When the form isn't loaded using jquery, no additional parameters are present in the forms action.

Comment: Not sure why jQuery would put that there, it will put things like that so it has a link to the control. were you asking the jquery to do anything on the form submit?

Comment: Yes, I use jquery to wire up a function call.  The function calls preventDefault() and makes an ajax call.

Comment: So that's the reason why then, because you are attaching jQuery to the submit event, it is adding a pointer in the code there.

Comment: Could you add a snippet of the jQuery code involved?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check what you are passing in on your edit link? I think you might have an encoding issue somewhere?

When you clicked on a link to edit your item it looks like it has pulled in an undefined parameter called `_`?

This info is used to choose the correct controller and action and also set the parameters in the controller's action on the submission return.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think hardcoding the `BeginForm` variables you might loose the id in the submit, unless you have it as a hidden variable?

P.S. If you are using mvc 3 look at using razor, its loads of fun...

instead of breaking in and out using `<% %>` you now use `@`

Comment: Luke, thanks for the reply.  I've 2 edit actions on the controller, one for httpget which take a nullable id as int and one for httppost that takes an id as int and the formcollection.  I have looked at razor, it's not an option for this project but it does look good!

Comment: Not an option? really? you sure :) you can still use the aspx and ascx views until you update or create new cshtml ones.  So the httpget is for the initial view and then the post handles the form submission. if you dont have the id defined as a hidden variable or in the action attribute I dont think it will pick the id up from in the Form Collection or the id parameter.